# Python conditional if statemnt

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with python and while learning I got an error while executing an `if` statement.

Could anyone suggest what I missed in my code?

> File "Demo_class2_Conditions.py", line 8
>      print(X)
>          ^
>   IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
X=int(input('Enter the value of X:'))
Y=int(input('Enter the value of Y:'))
Z=int(input('Enter the value of Z:'))
if X > Y:
        if X > Y:
        print(X)
        else:
        print(Y)
    else:
if Y > Z:
        if Y > Z:
        print(Y)
        else:
        print(Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always indent (2 or 4 spaces) statements belonging to the *block after conditions*.

Your example can - **properly indented** - look like this:

```
# first evaluation starts with no indentation
if X > Y: 
  print(X) # single statement (block 1) if previous condition satisfied
else:
  # block 2 begins
  print(Y)
  # block 2 ends

# second evaluation starts with no indentation
if Y > Z:
  print(Y) # block 3 has only 1 statement
else:
  print(Z) # single statement is block 4

# everything after evaluating is not indented
```